# How to add UIAutomationClient.dll and UIAutomationTypes.dll to .Net Core 5.0 project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, ui-automation

How to use `UIAutomationClient.dll` and `UIAutomationTypes.dll` in `.NET 5.0` project since there is no nuget package available!

I'm trying to convert a .NET Framework 4.8 project to .NET 5.0

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <TargetFrameworks>net48;net5.0-windows</TargetFrameworks>
        <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
        <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: .Net Core or .Net 5 (`.Net Core 5.0` doesn't exist)? What do you have in your Project's file, `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` or `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">`? If the former, do you have a `net5.0-windows` in `<TargetFrameworks>`? The UI Automation related assemblies are not cross-platform, but Windows-specific.

Comment: I updated the question (.NET 5.0 instead of .Net core 5.0)
I use net5.0-windows

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/3283 Looks like you'll need a reference to the windowsdesktop sdk in order to use the uiautomation libraries in a .net core project.

Comment: I migrated to https://github.com/FlaUI/FlaUI and it works great

Comment: @geek175...thank you!...I am just exploring my options...Appium w/ WindowsAppDriver is a joke compared to FlaUI.

Answer (score 10):

This .csproj is enough to use `System.Windows.Automation` (UIAutomation) in net5

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WPF"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: `Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App` is enough.